# How to remove files with special characters

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line

How to remove a file(s) with strange name in ubuntu?

I used ssh-keygen, I think I copied the command line with the linebreak at the end and created two files with a very strange file name.

https://ibb.co/0mC5fMj

Try to delete

```
rm \'\'$\'r\'
```

But result:

```
rm: cannot remove ''\'''\''$'\''r'\''': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why are you posting a link to an image of text?  Text output in a tty is easily copy-pasted directly into the question.

Comment: It appears that the path in question has the two characters '\' and 'r' in its name, rather than a single character represented by the escape sequence '\r'.  Try `rm "''$'\\r'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Try to add -- at the beginning of the file name.

```
$ rm -v -- #file
$ rm -v -- "#file"
```

- Try to add ./ at the beginning of the file name.

```
$ rm -v ./#file
```

- If the previous tips do not work, you can still remove it using the inode number with:

```
ls -li
```

output:

```
5133242 -rw-r--r-- 1 user #*%/file
```

then using find

```
$ find . -inum 5133242 -delete
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm this works